# Rogue Talents and Feat Prerequisites

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue

Does a rogue need to meet the prerequisites of a Combat Feat he or she gains via the Combat Trick talent?  Could I, for example, gain Spring Attack without Dodge and Mobility?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### A rogue needs to meet all prerequisites for the feats gained via Combat trick.

Take a look at the description of [Combat Trick](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/combat-trick)

> A rogue that selects this talent gains a bonus combat feat (see Feats).

and compare the rogue talent description to the [Monk Bonus feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Monk#TOC-Bonus-Feat)

> **Bonus Feat**
> [...]
> A monk need not have any of the prerequisites normally required for these feats to select them.

or the [Ranger Combat Style feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger#TOC-Combat-Style-Feat-Ex-)

> **Combat Style Feat (Ex)**
> [...]
> He can choose feats from his selected combat style, even if he does not have the normal prerequisites.
> [...]

Both of these abilities explicitly waive the prerequisites, while Combat Trick doesn't. Since having to qualify for feats is the norm, this *enabling* (in that it enables you do "go against the rules") text is important.